# Como receber um formData com arquivo e formulário na controller ? C #

Tags: c#, .net, asp

Assim recebo o formulário:

```
public JsonResult Import(**FormCollection** form)
```

Assim recebo o arquivo:

```
public JsonResult Import(**HttpPostedFileBase** file)

    $.ajax({
        url: urlImport,
        method: 'post',
        data: new FormData($('#formUpdate')[0],
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success === true) {
                ShowMessageSuccess('Process', result.MsgReturn);
            } else {
                ShowMessageError('Process', result.MsgReturn);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Esta faltando abrir o `{` na segunda função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom é muito simples, é só colocar os dois no mesmo método:

```
public JsonResult Import(FormCollection form, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Exemplo minimo:

***HTML***

```
<form name="formUpdate" id="formUpdate">
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button type="button" onclick="send();">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script>
    function send() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/save',
            method: 'post',
            data: new FormData($('#formUpdate')[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    return Json(new { });
}
```

***Observação:*** o nome do tipo `FormCollection` pode ser qualquer nome, já o `HttpPostedFileBase` precisa ser o mesmo nome do `input` que é do tipo `file`.